# Merge two dataframes on nearest value while duplicating rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes,

```
DF1 = NUM1     Car         COLOR 
      100     Honda       blue
      100     Honda       yellow
      200     Volvo       red

DF2 = NUM2     Car         STATE
      110     Honda        good
      110     Honda        bad
      230     Volvo        not bad
      230     Volvo        excellent
```

I want to merge them on nearest value in columns NUM1 & NUM2 in order to get this desired dataframe:

```
DF3 = NUM     CAR      COLOR     STATE
      100     HONDA     blue      good
      100     HONDA     blue      bad
      100     HONDA     yellow    good
      100     HONDA     yellow    bad
      200     VOLVO     red       not bad
      200     VOLVO     red       excellent
```

I've tried this:

```
df3 = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on="NUM1", right_on="NUM2")
```

But this is the result I get:

```
DF3 =     NUM     CAR      COLOR     STATE
          100     HONDA     blue      good
          100     HONDA     yellow    good
          200     VOLVO     red       not bad
```

Comment: You example is still ambiguous: `DF1.merge(DF2.drop(columns='NUM2'), on='Car')` gives the expected output

Comment: I'm trying to merge on NUM column not Car

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you might need to combine `merge_asof` and `merge`:

```
key = pd.merge_asof(DF1.reset_index().sort_values(by='NUM1'),
                    DF2['NUM2'],
                    left_on='NUM1', right_on='NUM2',
                    direction='nearest')['NUM2']

DF1.merge(DF2.drop(columns=DF1.columns.intersection(DF2.columns)),
          left_on=key, right_on='NUM2')
```